# Include a ActiveModel relational object for use in Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Hi I have the following question. Given there is a user that has_many Notes. And a Note belongs_to a user.

```
user = User.new(name:'John')
note = user.notes.new(title:'test')

user.delay.remind_me
```

I want that DJ also includes the notes and not only the user object. Is there a way to do this? I know it is better to only store a user_id into the DJ que but I don't want store this data to the DB so am trying this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remind_me` method should take care of retrieving the notes from the user. Like this:

```
def remind_me
  self.notes.each do |note|
    # do something
  end
end
```

But that said, I would suggest not storing the user object in the DelayedJob queue.

You can rather do something like this:

```
User.delay.remind(user_id)
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do it the clean way with the user_id. Thanks